# C++ Template Specialization: compile error: "is not a type"

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, specialization, partial-specialization

If I remove the template specialization part (the one that tries to print "Test 2"), the code compiles fine, but I'd like to be able to have a special case that runs a different code path that looks clean to outside users.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct SpecialType {};

template<typename A , typename B = SpecialType>
class Test
{
public:
    class TestInner
    {
    public:
        TestInner& operator* ();
    };
};

template<typename A , typename B>
typename Test<A , B>::TestInner& Test<A , B>::TestInner::operator* ()
{
    cout << "Test 1" << endl;
    return *this;
}

// If the following is removed, everything compiles/works, but I want this alternate code path:
template<typename A>
typename Test<A , SpecialType>::TestInner& Test<A , SpecialType>::TestInner::operator* ()
{
    cout << "Test 2" << endl;
    return *this;
}

int main()
{
    Test<int , SpecialType>::TestInner test;
    *test;

   return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
By the way, the compiler error reads:

```
main.cpp:26:44: error: 'Test<A, SpecialType>::TestInner' is not a type
 typename Test<A , SpecialType>::TestInner& Test<A , SpecialType>::TestInner::operator* ()
                                            ^
main.cpp:26:89: error: invalid use of dependent type 'typename Test<A, SpecialType>::TestInner'
 typename Test<A , SpecialType>::TestInner& Test<A , SpecialType>::TestInner::operator* ()
                                                                                         ^
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a declaration for the specialised class:

```
template<typename A>
class Test<A, SpecialType>
{
public:
    class TestInner
    {
    public:
        TestInner& operator* ();
    };
};
```

The problem is that you define an member for a specialization that is not declared. A specialization of a templated class does not share any members or methods with the generalised template, so the declaration of the generalised template doesn't serve as a declaration of any specialisations of that template class.

Consider this:

```
template <class T>
class Foo {
  void GeneralFunction(T x);
}
```

and a specialization:

```
template <>
class Foo<int> {
  void SpecialisedFunction(int x);
}
```

Here, `Foo</*anything except int*/>` has only the method `GeneralFunction` whereas `Foo<int>` has only the method `SpecialisedFunction`.

By the same logic, this is allowed also:

```
template<>
class Foo<float> {
  float GeneralFunction; //here GeneralFunction is a data member, not a method.
}
```

Long story short you need to declare you specialisation.

Comment: Thank you.  Quick followup question: if class Test<A,B> had other functions, is there any clean way I could inherit the rest of the functionality into Test<A,SpecialType> but only specialize that one function?  I'm trying to avoid mass code duplication.

Comment: @Jonathan As far as I know not by using only template specialisations. You could maybe achieve something by mixing inheritance.

Comment: @Jonathan done a little research: what you want is to use 'Curiously Recurring Template Pattern'. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6220337/code-duplication-and-template-specialization-when-the-specialized-function-has http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757816/class-template-specializations-with-shared-functionality

Comment: Just wanted to add: I ran across this post (http://stackoverflow.com/a/3057522/1917447) which helped me solve what I was trying to accomplish.